# Class level validator not applicable to field in spring

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I have a custom interface:

```
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { MyCustomValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface ValidData {

    String message() default EMPTY;

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

}
```

and I have a class that - until now - had this validator attached:

```
@ValidData(groups = AfterDefaultGroup.class)
public class RecoverData {

    private String data;
```

It works, but I need to move the validator from class level to field level. I tried this:

```
public class RecoverData {

    @ValidData(groups = AfterDefaultGroup.class)
    private String data;
```

but I'm getting compilation error here:

```
ValidData not applicable to field
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Target` annotation defines where this annotation can be applied.
You are restricting it to `TYPE` and `ANNOTATION_TYPE`right now which doesn't allow to use it on fields.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) you have to use `ElementType.FIELD`